# Divs/text moving when i zoom in and zoom out HTML/CSS/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, zooming

I'm new to coding world. I have problem with my Navbar, on 100% zoom on browser it's everything okay,but when i zoom in 150% scale everything will be messed. How can i fix everything to be on the same size when somebody zoom in and zoom out? Thank you in advance.

[ZOOM WITH 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfdOO.png)

[ZOOM WITH 150%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejjCE.png)

[ZOOM WITH 200%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJGy6.png)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.pre-header {
    background-color: #111618;
    height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 15px;

}

.pre-header .secondary-menu {
    list-style: none;
}

.pre-header .secondary-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.pre-header .secondary-menu li a {
    color: #787374;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-nav .main-menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.main-nav .main-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}

.main-nav .main-menu li a {
    color: #767676;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-nav img {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.main-nav .main-menu .free-quote-btn a {

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="probaferomotosajta.css">
    <title>Feromoto - Hidraulicna creva</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="pre-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>UNDER ATTACK? - S.O.S LINE 880.000.800</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">                  
                    <ul class="secondary-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Presale Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Whitepapers</a></li>
                    </ul>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="main-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="slika1.png" width="120" height="120" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <ul class="main-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rating</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Job</a></li>
                        <li class="free-quote-btn"><a href="#">Free Quote</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because window width decreases when you zoom in your browser.
So you can fix it by using `@media` query.